# How can I toggle between functions on the same button depending on the menu tab that is active with VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, button, vue-component

I'm finishing my web application and I'm struggling with some code. I got 2 tabs in a page, depending on the tab the button will trigger a function, for example if i'm in the first tab, the button click will call an function to do something in the specific tab, and if I'm in the second tab (the 2nd tab is the active one), my button (I'm talking about the same button of course) will trigger another function on the second tab.

I'm using a button created with a Vue component, inside I got one function (for the first tab), and then the second function is another Vue instance declared outside of the component.

```
Vue component('buttonMaster', {
template: '<div id="sys" v-if="tab_main"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm rounded m1-2" @click="sendTrad" id="but" name="but">EXAMPLE</button></div>'

methods: {
    sendT: function (event) {
        'some code' 
  }
});
```

And ton the second hand a vue instance with the second function:

```
let example = new Vue({

el: '#butt2',   
methods: {
    sendP: function() {
        'another code'  
   }
});
```

I was thinking to implement a v-if in the template like:

```
<div id="butt" v-if="tab_main"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm rounded m1-2" @click="sendT" id="butt" name="butt">EXAMPLE</button></div>    
+
<div id="butt2"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm rounded m1-2" @click="sendP" id="butt2" name="butt2">EXAMPLE_2</button></div>
```

But I don't get it, should I create a simple button? or I'm just misunderstanding how v-if conditional work ?

Comment: What do you mean by “another Vue instance running outside the component”? I would recommend creating a single vue app where the two Tabs are components. Then each tab can pass a different variable to the click function.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what are you saying, could you give me a basic 1+1 = 2 example please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is basically 2 ways to do that. 
First - use v-if and v-else and duplicate the buttons (depending on the tab selected) and each one call a diferente function.

```
template: '<div id="sys" v-if="tab_main"><button @click="sendTrad" id="but" name="but">EXAMPLE</button></div>'
template: '<div id="sys2" v-if="!tab_main"><button @click="sendSecondaryTrad" id="but2" name="but2">EXAMPLE</button></div>'
```

Second - on the function logic your verify what tab is selected and change your executed code base on it.

```
methods: {
   sendT(event) {
      if (this.tab_main) {
        //do Something
      } else {
        // do other thing
      }
   }
};
```